# Visualizing/saving an extremely large number of pixels with

Tags: c++, image, visual-c++, sfml, mandelbrot

I made a program in C++ which calculates the `mandelbrot-set`. Now I want to visualize it (save it in a picture). But when I try to save a `64k` picture some problems come up. So what is the best way to save a picture of the pixels or at least to visual it?

**Edit:**

When I want to create a for Example `64K` (61440 * 34560) image there will be the error "Access violation while writing at the position `0x0`..." (originally on German and translated) and the program stops. This error appears with very high resolution. On lower resolutions the program works as it is supposed to.

```
#include <SFML\Graphics.hpp>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <complex>
#include <cmath>
#include <thread>

//4K :   3840 *  2160
//8K :   7680 *  4320
//16K:  15360 *  8640
//32K:  30720 * 17280
//64K:  61440 * 34560
//128K:122880 * 69120


const unsigned long width  = 61440; //should be dividable by ratioX & numberOfThreads!
const unsigned long height = 34560; //should be dividable by ratioY & numberOfThreads!

const unsigned int maxIterations = 500;

const unsigned int numberOfThreads = 6;

const int maxWidth = width / 3;
const int maxHeight = height / 2;
const int minWidth = -maxWidth * 2;
const int minHeight = -maxHeight;

const double ratioX = 3.0 / width;
const double ratioY = 2.0 / height;

sf::Image img = sf::Image();


int getsGreaterThan2(std::complex<double> z, int noIterations) {
    double result;
    std::complex<double> zTmp = z;
    std::complex<double> c = z;
    for (int i = 1; i != noIterations; i++) {
        zTmp = std::pow(z, 2) + c;
        if (zTmp == z) {
            return 0;
        }
        z = std::pow(z, 2) + c;
        result = std::sqrt(std::pow(z.real(), 2) + std::pow(z.imag(), 2));
        if (result > 2) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}


void fillPixelArrayThreadFunc(int noThreads, int threadNr) { //threadNr ... starts from 0

    double imgNumber;
    double realNumber;

    double tmp;

    long startWidth = ((double)width) / noThreads * threadNr + minWidth;
    long endWidth = startWidth + width / noThreads;

    for (long x = startWidth; x < endWidth; x++) {
        imgNumber = x * ratioX;
        for (long y = minHeight; y < maxHeight; y++) {
            realNumber = y * ratioY;
            long xArray = x - minWidth;
            long yArray = y - minHeight;
            tmp = getsGreaterThan2(std::complex<double>(imgNumber, realNumber), maxIterations);
            if (tmp == 0) {
                img.setPixel(xArray, yArray, sf::Color(0, 0, 0, 255));
            }
            else {
                img.setPixel(xArray, yArray, sf::Color(tmp / maxIterations * 128, tmp / maxIterations * 128, tmp / maxIterations * 255, 255));
            }
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    img.create(width, height, sf::Color::Black);

    std::thread *threads = new std::thread[numberOfThreads];
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfThreads; i++) {
        threads[i] = std::thread(std::bind(fillPixelArrayThreadFunc, numberOfThreads, i));
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfThreads; i++) {
        threads[i].join();
    }

    img.saveToFile("filename.png");
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: _when I try to save a 64k picture some problems come up_... And what exactly are these problems? You cannot expect anyone to give a valid answer with such a vague description.

Comment: What picture format are you saving as: JPEG?  TIFF?  PNG?  GIF?  BMP? WMF? Are there any size limitations for the format you are using?

Comment: I am sorry for the bad explaination. It was rather meant as a general question of how to save it properly (which file-format/methods). But I will upload my code shortly.

Comment: **Q:** _how to save it properly (which file-format/methods)_? **A:** by writing the correct code for the file-format (jpeg, bmp, or whatever) you want. Sorry, but your question Is really too general, it's somewhat like asking: _How do I write a text processor?_.

Comment: Did you run it with a debugger ?

Comment: TIFF has an extension for extremely large images, and you want to be using that.

Comment: @MichaelWalz I used the debugger of Visual Studio 2015

Comment: And __where__ did it crash ?

Comment: @MichaelWalz It crashed at "img.setPixel(xArray, yArray, sf::Color(tmp / maxIterations * 128, tmp / maxIterations * 128, tmp / maxIterations * 255, 255));" (Line 75 in fillPixelArrayThreadFunc)

Comment: @SgtDomo this looks like a problem in `img.setPixel` which is not your code. So it's certainly a bug or a limitation in SFML. Maybe you should compile your program as 64 bit program.

Comment: @MichaelWalz as far as I know I already compile it as a 64bit program

Comment: @SgtDomo I'm compiling it as 32 bit and your program boils down allocating 4198498343 bytes which cannot be handled. BTW: have a look in the Visual Studio Output window: I'm getting this message: `Exception thrown at 0x75BFC41F in testco.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::bad_alloc at memory location 0x0069F65C.`.

Comment: @MichaelWalz I think I'm getting the same message (how I already said, it's unfortunately on german). But I'm running it as debug with x64 which is 64bit, right?

Comment: @SgtDomo, yes it's 64 bit. Try to step through the SFML code, but it's certainly some limitation. With 122'880 * 69'120 pixels (= 8'493'465'600) and 3 bytes per pixel you need to allocate 25'480'396'800 bytes ~24 Gb for the image and that's probably more than your system can handle. Just try `malloc(24000000000)` and look if that works.

Answer (score 0):

Your program fails during the call  `img.create(width, height, sf::Color::Black);`.

When you step into the `sf::Image::create` function you end up here where the `newPixels` vector is created, this simply fails when `width * height` is too big as in your case:

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void Image::create(unsigned int width, unsigned int height, const Color& color)
{
    if (width && height)
    {
        // Create a new pixel buffer first for exception safety's sake
        std::vector<Uint8> newPixels(width * height * 4);
                                     ^61440* ^34560 = 8'493'465'600 bytes !!
```

Conclusion: SFML cannot handle huge images.

Comment: Thank you! I guess I have to find a different way to visualize it.

Comment: Creating several smaller images and stitching them together might be a way to go.

Comment: but I would still have to use something else to stitch them together, because even if I begin with smaller images, the size of the end-image won't change

Comment: Yes you need something else. Anyway this is not trivial. Maybe [this](https://sites.google.com/site/openimageio/home) helps.